# How to parse a telegram story with telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am executing a method to load a list of channel messages

```
result = await client(GetMessagesRequest('https://t.me/+EFH53IOJSADif1', [2]))
```

I get:

```
media=MessageMediaStory(user_id=6468649006, id=1, via_mention=False, story=None)
```

I don’t understand where the raw data is and how I can download it

And is it possible to get not the `MessageMediaStory` type, but just raw data and work with it, and all this in Telethon?

Answer (score 0):

`MessageMediaStory` is the "raw data" parsed into objects.

If you want the decrypted data Telegram sent, you can use `bytes(result)`, however, this will be an unreadable serialized mess.

Telethon's v1 FAQ has:

> **How do I access a field?**
>
> This is basic Python knowledge. You should use the dot operator:
>
> ```py
> #       ^ we used the dot operator to access the username attribute
>
> result = await client(functions.photos.GetUserPhotosRequest(
>     user_id='me',
>     offset=0,
>     max_id=0,
>     limit=100 ))
>
> # Working with list is also pretty basic print(result.photos[0].sizes[-1].type)
> #           ^       ^ ^       ^ ^
> #           |       | |       | \ type
> #           |       | |       \ last size
> #           |       | \ list of sizes
> #  access   |       \ first photo from the list
> #  the...   \ list of photos
> #
> # To print all, you could do (or mix-and-match): for photo in result.photos:
>     for size in photo.sizes:
>         print(size.type)
> ```

`MessageMediaStory` is no different:

```py
await client.download_media(result.story.media)
#            ^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#            download                    media
```

If your `story is None`, that means there's no story there. Remember to update. There might be a different method to fetch stories, or there might be none here.